Does the forward oblique shock on a supersonic wedge airfoil reduce the lift created by the lower surface?
In the supersonic region of flight, oblique shockwaves form. For this question, I am specifically focusing on the effects of the forward oblique shock (A) as seen in the image below.
My main question revolves around the behavior of airflow on the lower surface of the wedge:
Since the front oblique shock reorients the airflow so that it becomes parallel to the lower (and upper) surface of the wing, does this mean that the lower surface contributes less to lift production at supersonic speeds? Does the flow turning caused by the shockwave reduce the upward force imparted by the lower surface, effectively diminishing its role in overall lift production?

Essentially, because the airflow is made parallel to the lower surface  by the forward oblique shock, does this decrease the amount of air redirected by the lower surface therefore decreasing lift?


Flow is always parallel to a surface.  Otherwise, it would go through the surface -- and that can't happen.

@RobMcDonald Yes, but work has to be done to make the flow parallel to the surface. In subsonic speeds, the work is done by the surface of the wing, and in supersonic speeds the work is done by the shockwave. (Some of the above might be incorrect or inaccurate, as I'm not 100% sure)

The lower surface of a wing is no different from the upper surface.  Aerodynamics doesn't care.  Your question does not include enough information.  Are you considering a blunt nose airfoil with a bow shock out front -- or are you considering a supersonic diamond or wedge airfoil?  Are you talking about a normal shock on the airfoil's curved surface?  BTW, don't forget that flow behind a bow shock is subsonic.

@RobMcDonald Good point. I somehow forgot the bow shock is a normal shock in most cases. Because of that, it doesn't really make sense to use an airfoil in my question so I changed it to a wedge airfoil instead, where the bow shock is more likely to be an oblique shock. Thanks.

You should edit your question further to remove the words about bow and replace with oblique, etc.  Overall, your question is not very clear.  The image you selected is very pretty, but was clearly re-drawn by someone who does not understand superosnic aerodynamics -- the front top surface is drawn essentially parallel to the freestream flow -- which would cause there to be no shock on the top front surface.
Lift is always produced by a pressure difference -- delta P.  In this case of supersonic flow, the highest pressure (by a lot) will be on the lower surface front.

@RobMcDonald I made a few edits. Is it better? I am still planning to edit some more clarity into it.

You've switched to a diagram at zero angle of attack -- where there is no lift at all.  Bottom line 1) the lower surface has no inherent lifting ability.  Lift is caused by a delta in pressure, you can't consider one part in isolation.  2) Supersonic flow has almost nothing to do with subsonic flow.  Everything changes.  In a subsonic flow, the lower surface might see approximately ambient pressure, with acceleration over the top surface causing lower pressure -- delta P causing lift.

In the supersonic flow, the oblique shocks on the top and bottom both cause pressure to increase.  Typically, the bottom surface turns more than the top, so its shock is stronger, and the pressure jump is larger.  DeltaP -- it makes lift.

Does this answer help?

@RobMcDonald Ah okay. Because this question got downvoted, I changed the picture again. This one is actually at AoA so it is making lift, and I added a small summarization at the end. Besides that, I'm having a hard time understanding what else needs improvement. - I did not think of the fact that shockwaves have a pressure jump themselves, which definitely makes sense.

All the words about transitioning from subsonic to supersonic -- and acceleration of the flow -- do not add to the question.  This is a simple question about supersonic flow.  All the other words are distracting fluff.

You can't forget about the pressure jump through a shock -- that is the main thing a shock does.

@RobMcDonald I will make another edit to remove the unnecessary wording. I also think a better response from me would've been "I did not think of the fact that the pressure jump from shockwaves could increase / change the lift". Just bad wording on my part haha.


Since the front oblique shock reorients the airflow so that it becomes parallel to the surface of the wing, does this mean that the lower surface contributes less to lift?

Yes. Since pressure acts perpendicularly to the surface if that surface points for example upward and forward then it produces drag other than lift.
Regarding the diamond airfoil in your picture: Behind a shock wave pressure rises while behind an expansion fan it decreases. That implies that:

on the surfaces B, the aerodynamic force mainly pushes downward and backward;
on the surfaces B', the aerodynamic force mainly pushes upward and backward:
on the surfaces D, the aerodynamic force mainly pulls upward and backward:
and on the surfaces D', the aerodynamic force mainly pulls downward and backward.

The sum of the forces acting backward obviously gives rise to a drag which is the well know "wave drag" typical of supersonic speeds. The sum of the forces acting upward/downward obviously gives the lift.
